# How are POST requests constructed?

Tags: http, post, browser, https, http-post

How does a web browser construct a valid HTTP POST request from HTML source code?

For example, the login form on [https://stackexchange.com/users/login](https://stackexchange.com) looks like:

```html
<form method="post" action="/affiliate/form/login/submit">
        <table class="position-table">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="input-td">
                    <label for="email" class="accessibility-hidden">Email</label>
                    <input class="framed-text-field edit-field-overlayed" type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="100" style="opacity: 0.3; z-index: 1; position: relative;">
                    <span class="form-help" style="display: none;">name@example.com</span>
                </td>
                <td class="input-td">
                    <label for="password" class="accessibility-hidden">Password</label>
                    <input class="framed-text-field edit-field-overlayed" type="password" name="password" id="password" style="opacity: 0.3; z-index: 1; position: relative;">
                    <span class="form-help" style="display: none;">Password</span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="input-td">
                    <input type="submit" class="affiliate-button" value="Sign In">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <input type="hidden" name="affId" value="XX">
        <input type="hidden" id="fkey" name="fkey" value="XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX">
    </form>
```

If I intercept the request my browser sends, I can see the full POST request to be:

```
POST /affiliate/form/login/submit HTTP/1.1
Host: openid.stackexchange.com
Connection: close
Content-Length: 86
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://openid.stackexchange.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://openid.stackexchange.com/affiliate/form?affId=11&background=transparent&callback=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2fusers%2fauthenticate&color=black&nonce=ZUlWWgAAAADlmwCfYbAw%2bg%3d%3d&openid.sreg.requested=email&signupByDefault=false&onLoad=signin-loaded&authCode=E8UrPSRT%2bzAs6b2nqZygJVS2cHb%2fY8TwtrlMUN3bORnP0o7IZRGIatV%2fkJ73KMX0nwrcnJdf2qBKFzJJ28czMo9GWAQesGoO4qgp6XZgulhYzlpEL4XOpTotYAVSlq5K5mFQjwTy6I4YbtJrsIyFs4yy2EgNlOe%2b7E0W%2fRVpnws%3d
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: prov=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX; acct=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXvXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; canary=X; anon=XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX

email=AzureDiamond&password=Hunter2&affId=11&fkey=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
```

How does my web browser (chrome) know to construct the POST request based on what it can see in the form HTML? Certain aspects are obvious, request method, target, content-length, the actual etc is all visible in the form (or entered by the user).

The headers that I don't understand the construction of are:

- Cache-Control
- Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
- Content-Type
- Accept
- Refer
- Accept-Encoding
- Accept-Language

Are these built into/written by the browser? I don't think so because when I try stripping them from the request, I get bad request errors back from stackexchange. However I can't seem to find what the browser builds them from?

Answer (score 0):

The browser assumes that a data requested by a form will not be static, and therefore knows to set "Cache-Control: max-age=0".  Similar default assumptions are made by browsers for the other request headers.

However, it is possible to override some defaults with `<META` tags: [enter link description here](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html) (which I found linked to under a similar question here at StackOverflow).  Others are set as form attributes, like `<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"`...